# Get the Window which called the Function/Method

Tags: c#

How can i get the window which called a function or a method from another class

Example:

```
public static String Caller(Window window = Caller) //Caller=the caller window
{
    return window.Name;
}
```

Comment: Require a `Window` as a parameter and then send it directly to the function when you call it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Do i have to pass it to the function? is there anyway else?

Comment: if you don't pass it, how will you know who called you ? what about if different windows/applications are calling your method which resides in a dll?

Comment: What i meant is something like `[CallerMemberName] string Caller = ""` which gets the method caller name, without the need to pass it.

Comment: there is no such convenient way like `[CallerMemberName]` to get the Window that calls the method. Why do you want to get the Window Name? There can be some other way since I guess you need it for diagnostic purpose.

Comment: There is no corresponding attribute for arbitrary classes. It's not generally useful either, because it would prevent people from calling your method from a helper function.